# Docker mysql stop with exit(1)

Tags: mysql, docker

I was trying to bring up my MySql in the docker container. But, it stopped with code exited(1). Here is how I run it:

`docker run --name demo-db -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/var/lib/mysql`

Here is the log of the container

```
Initializing database
2018-10-12T17:50:42.694183Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2018-10-12T17:50:42.694277Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) initializing of server in progress as process 31
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
2018-10-12T17:51:10.497527Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] unknown option '--mount'
2018-10-12T17:51:10.497543Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. If you have upgraded your server, make sure you're executing mysql_upgrade to correct the issue.
2018-10-12T17:51:10.497551Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-10-12T17:51:14.130241Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.12)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Please help me...

Comment: I haven't used Docker in a year, but I don't recognize that --mount syntax. I remember something like  -v /path/to/foo:/path/to/var

Comment: @wbg with the newer versions of docker, one can use the `--mount` flag for standalone containers

Answer (score 0):

Better answer may follow, I used to use Docker as well for MySQL but it's been a while.

Start as detached container:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/var/lib/mysql --name demo-db -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest
```

Then attach to it like so:

```
docker run -i -t demo-db /bin/bash
```

Note about `pwd` use:

There's no need to use the `pwd` command, just get the shell variable `$PWD`. When you do `foo=$(pwd)` is kind of overkill, b/c you're actually running the `pwd` command in a sub shell to return `$PWD`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `docker run` command is basically

```
docker run <docker run options> IMAGE <command and arguments>
```

So when you run:

```sh
docker run \
  --name demo-db -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d \
  mysql:latest \
  --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/var/lib/mysql
```

The `--mount` option is *after* the image name, so it's passed as an argument to the container.  Move this option *before* `mysql:latest` and you'll be set.